# How much does the GCC compilers keep to the C/C++ standards?

Tags: gcc, c99, c++03

For example, the C programming language with C99 standard supports hexadecimal floating-point literals but the C++ with C++03 standard doesn't.

I tested it, GCC recognized the hexadecimal floating literal in C++03 mode (-std=c++03) but according to the C++ standard, it shouldn't. I know, it's not a tragedy, I'm just interested in this question..

Does the GCC compilers conform to the standards? Can you recommend me a C/C++ compiler that conforms to the standards "perfectly"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you give a standard to the GCC, according to the [manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#C-Dialect-Options) the

> compiler will accept all programs following that standard and those using GNU extensions that do not contradict it.

If you want to ensure strict adherence to the standard, add `-pedantic`, which will warn about hex FP literals.

Comment: @user2148758: Glad to help. The common way to say "thanks" is to accept the answer with the checkmark below the score.

Comment: Jeah, I'm a newbie :) Thanks

Comment: @user2148758: Then let me welcome you on StackOverflow, have a good time.

Answer (score 0):

The Comeau compiler, using its own libcomo standard library, is about as close to perfect C++03 support as you can get.

For C++11 Clang with libc++ and GCC with libstdc++ are both pretty good, but not perfect (yet)